# Prisma Self referencing tables error on Delete. cannot Cascade

Tags: javascript, mongodb, prisma, self-referencing-table

I'm trying to make a CLI application using prisma.

In my `schema.prisma` file I have a `Folder` and `Phew` table to make the "filesystem"

I want to delete all sub-folders and phews when a parent is deleted.

I tried to "Cascade" but it throws an error

> Error validating: A self-relation must have `onDelete` and `onUpdate` referential actions set to `NoAction` in one of the @relation attributes. Read more at https://pris.ly/d/cyclic-referential-actions

Here is the `Folder` schema:

```
model Folder {
  folder_id        String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name             String
  readonly         Boolean  @default(false)
  private          Boolean  @default(true)
  // relations
  user_id          String   @db.ObjectId
  user             User     @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [user_id], onDelete: Cascade)
  phews            Phew[]
  Folders          Folder[] @relation(name: "parent")
  parent           Folder?  @relation(name: "parent", fields: [parent_folder_id], references: [folder_id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  parent_folder_id String?  @db.ObjectId
  // timestamps
  createdAt        DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt        DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

I read this [docs](https://pris.ly/d/cyclic-referential-actions) but I didn't find a way to solve this.

Comment: The same issue with me